# enlarging an element by hover makes strange behaviour

Tags: html, css, hover, nav

Having this html:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix::after{
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 602px;
}

header{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

header img{
    float:left;
}

header h1{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

header ul{
    list-style: none;
}

header li{
    float:left; 
    font-size: 1.05em; 
    padding-right: 6%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

header a{
    vertical-align: sub;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e0e0c0;
    padding-left: 2px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

header a:hover{
    background: #5a288d;
    color:#f0f0f0;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <img src='../data/img/pap_white.png' height="130" width="130" alt="Papaluz logo">
        <h1>Papaluz Consulting</h1>
        <nav class="clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src='../data/img/arrow_white.svg'>Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="../data/img/arrow_white.svg">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src='../data/img/arrow_white.svg'>Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src='../data/img/arrow_white.svg'>About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

When you hover over the last list item , the item cannot "decide" wheter to go to next line of stay on the original. So the result is the absurd behaviour, where you are "stuck" (just try to hover over the last navigation item `About`.

1. How to solve that bizarre behaviour of hovering over last item?
2. I would also like to solve the problem of "guessing the right padding according to number of items". I am talking. Here:

   header li{
   padding-right: 6%;
   }

I have to always change the percent number according to number of element. That is, If I want to add another menu item, the number must be smaller in order to have the menu items equally arrange. I would like to set the padding to automatically fit the best padding, so they will be equally arranged (and no item would be out of line). How to achive this with `display: inline-block`?

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue you are describing when hovering over the last item. What is your screen size / browser? Also, are you sure you don't want to assign clearfix to ```::before``` vs ```:after```? The nav is being pushed to the right due to the floats before it.

Comment: use padding fully.not like that you have used e.g padding-right this is wrong method. use it padding: 15px 10px; and add clearfix to header because inner element are floating